# Java concurrent hashmap indexed by an array declaration issues

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, hashmap

I'm trying to generate concurrent hashmaps indexed by an array. My application launches multiple threads which may store data in the hashmap indexed by a profile id -> Multiple threads may save to the same hashmap. For quick access i've tried to generate an indexed concurrent hashmap like this:

```
public static ConcurrentHashMap<String,Integer> profiledata[] = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,Integer>();
```

Then when a thread is launched, it checks if the index of that hashmap is set, if not it sets it like so:

```
try {
        System.out.println(">> Trying profiledata."+profiledata[thisid].isEmpty());
    } catch (NullPointerException e) { 
        System.out.println("profiledata["+thisid+"] not set... initialising");
        profiledata[thisid] = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();
      }
```

I hope it can declare the hashmap like this as the value thisid is dynamic.

I understand maybe I could set this as a multidimensional concurrent hashmap, if anyone could recommend me on how best to do this i'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not "a concurrent hashmap indexed by an array", it's "an array of concurrent hashmaps".

Comment: What exactly are you trying to use as a key in this HashMap? If it's just a profile ID, then where does the array come in?